# LIKE a detail page inside iframe app in tab

Tags: tabs, facebook-iframe, iframe-app

We have a facebook app that's running inside an IFRAME on a fan page TAB.

On the main page of the app, we show e.g. 10 books and users can click through to the detail page of one single book.

We want to add a LIKE button on those detail pages, so that users on facebook can like and share that book in their stream.

The problem is that facebook doesn't provide a way to like a detail page inside an iframe, as far as we can see.

Does anyone know how to solve this?
We want the liked link, to link directly to our application inside the tab of the fan page where our application has been added, in other words: when a user likes a book, others should be able to click on that liked link and see the book in the tabbed app

Comment: I have the same issue. Could we get more information on this? It's not very clear how this might work. How do you generate a url for the stream which will link to a page and application tab and then load the like url into the iFrame?

Comment: it appears that you are not able to like pages inside an iframe app, when it's used as a tabbed application. You can do it when you are using a canvas app (not inside a user's tab) because then you have different url's to access

Comment: @Jorre It is possible. Dustin's answer is correct and is how I have solved the problem in the past. Use the app_data field to pass in the url of the page you wish to load (eg. /content/12) and then, when the canvas app loads, check if app_data is set and if so, return a 303 redirect to /contents/12 (or whatever the contents of app_data is).

Answer (score 1):

You might possible be able to use the app_data field to accomplish what you're looking for.  Check https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/ for more info.  This should allow for unique url's that you can trigger your page to respond to.

Comment: Thanks for the link but having some code would be helpful as well.